# How to convert Navbar to widget menu in yii2

Tags: widget, yii2, icons, html-lists

I have a Navbar menu that want to convert to widget menu.

This is my Navbar:

```
<div id='wrapper'>
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <section id='sidebar'>
            <i class='icon-align-justify icon-large' id='toggle'></i>
            <ul id='dock'>
                <li class='launcher dropdown hover'>
            <i class='icon-flag'></i>
            <a href='#'>Reports</a>
            <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
                <li class='dropdown-header'>Launcher description</li>
                <li>
                    <a href='#'>Action</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
            </ul>
            <div data-toggle='tooltip' id='beaker' title='Made by lab2023'></div>
        </section>
 </div>
```

and This my widget:

```
<?php  echo '<br> menu test<br>' . Menu::widget([
        'items' => [
            ['label' => 'Reports', 'url' => ['product/index'], 'class' => 'launcher dropdown hover', 'items' => [
                ['label' => 'Action'],
            ]],
        ],
    ]);
?>
```

How to add `<li class='dropdown-header'>description</li>` and `<i class='icon-flag'></i>` and `<ul id='dock'>` to widget menu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

disable menu encode using `'encodeLabels'=>false,`

Then use :

`['label' => '<i class='icon-align-justify icon-large' id='toggle'></i>...'`